# how do i increase the min and max on my number list?

Tags: python, python-3.2

I'm creating a game in python but I ran into trouble when creating the level system. ya see for her attack I created A list from 1(min) to 10(max) and for every level she gains I want the min and the max of the list to increase by 1 but how should i do it if it is possible? I'm coding in python 3.2

```
char ={
    'atk':[1,10],
    'Hp':100,
    'name': 'Ruby',
    'Age': 1,
    'weapon': 'Scythe',
    'lvl': 1,
    'xp': 0,
    'nextlvl': 50,
    'stats': {
        'str': 1,
        'dex': 1,
        'vit': 1
}}
while char['xp'] >= char['nextlvl']:
    char['lvl'] += 1
    char['nextlvl'] = char['nextlvl'] * 3
    char['stats']['str'] +=1
    char['stats']['dex'] +=1
    char['stats']['vit'] +=1
    char['atk'] +=1 <-- my problems right here
    print('level:', char['lvl'],'Exp:', char['xp'],'nextlvl:', char['nextlvl'])
    print('STR:', char['stats']['str'], 'DEX:', char['stats']['dex'], 'VIT:', char['stats']['vit'])
```

Comment: why don't you use one value for min, another for max and just use the key? `d["atk_mn"] += 1;d["atk_mx"] += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
char['atk'] = [atk + 1 for atk in char['atk']]
```

You could also increment the two numbers (the min and the max) individually:

```
char['atk'][0] = char['atk'][0] + 1
char['atk'][1] = char['atk'][1] + 1
```

If you think this unwieldy, you might want to consider storing the min and the max in two separate dictionary entries.